# Shrinking Spiral Square - Processing

Tags: processing

I'm trying as a task given to create a pattern of 20 squares that are 500x500px and in the middle of a screen size of 600x600px. With each one slightly smaller and rotated by 1o and each one with an alpha value of 40. I have attached an image what it needs to look like. I have no idea how to start it and may need a lot of assistance. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: "I have no idea how to start it" -- Just start it. *Experiment*. Processing is a very hands-on language which gives you almost instant visual feedback. Draw a square. Experiment with rotating a square. Experiment with making it smaller. Etc. Don't deprive yourself of the joy of figuring out something on your own.  "... and may need a lot of assistance". Why not post a more focused question if and when you get to the point of needing assistance? I am voting to close this question as "too broad".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw the rectangles by using the function [`rect`](https://processing.org/reference/rect_.html) in a loop.
Set the fill color with an alpha channel. Since the default belnd mode is [`BLEND`](https://processing.org/reference/blendMode_.html), the objects are blendend. This means, if more objects are drawn at the same place, then the scene will become more saturated at this parts.
Use [`scale`](https://processing.org/reference/scale_.html) and [`rotate`](https://processing.org/reference/rotate_.html) to consecutively change the model matrix, but reset the model matrix at the begin of each loop iteration by [`resetMatrix`](https://processing.org/reference/resetMatrix_.html).
The amount of the angle of rotation does not linear increase, but it increases more as the index `i` increases.

```
void setup(){
    size(500,500);
}

float angle_degree  = 1.1;
float scale_percent = 3.7;
float size = 400;
void draw() {

    background(255);

    stroke(0);
    fill(0,0,255,40);

    float current_ang = 0;
    float current_scale = 1.0;
    for( int i=0;i < 20; ++i ) {

        resetMatrix();
        translate(width/2, height/2);

        scale(current_scale);
        rotate(current_ang);

        rect(-size/2, -size/2, size, size);

        current_scale -= scale_percent / 100.0;
        current_ang -= i * angle_degree * PI/180.0;
    }
}
```

Preview:

[image]

Comment: So what happens if want to rotate it by 1 degree. what would i change???

Comment: @Kobe `rotate(PI/180.0);` - Note the angle has to be in a [radian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) and `2.0*PI` match 360 degrees. `PI/20.0` (like in the answer) are 9 degrees

Comment: But when I change the size to 600,600 it's no longer in the middle. what else do i need to change

Comment: @Kobe I change the answer. See the parameters `angle_degree`, `scale_percent`, `size`. `translate(width/2, height/2)` keeps it in the middle.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I don't think that you deserve a downvote. My guess is that some people object to answering homework questions. I tend to reserve downvotes in those situations to the person that asked the homework question rather than the person who answered it. In this case, the question isn't quite awful and your answer is good enough to if anything merit an upvote (+1), although I still think that the question itself should be closed.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you, and I agree with *"I still think that the question itself should be closed."*